# Encoded characters showing up in results

Tags: sql

When I execute sql on my csv sometimes in the results we get symbols like Â. I found the entry and rewrote the numbers out and fixed it. But I am curious as to what would do that?

and in the future can I add some sort of character encode checker to make sure it spits out normally?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'normal'?  You tend to see those characters when you have utf8-encoded characters stored in a latin1-encoded table.  Or the other way around.  I can't remember.  I saw this in an old WordPress installation I was trying to migrate and upgrade.  Check your table encodings.